# Set datasource for custom itemWriter (spring batch)

Tags: datasource, spring-batch

I want to read from a database and write to another database using a custom itemWriter.
How can I set datasource for custom itemWriter?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this sample project [Spring Batch Example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-example-csv-file-to-database/)

Here is sample code for your custom `ItemWriter`.

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.x.y.z.MyBean;

@Component("myJdbcWriter")
public class MyCustomJdbcWriter extends JdbcBatchItemWriter<MyBean> {

    MyCustomJdbcWriter() {

    }

    @Override
    @Resource
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    // define other methods also that you want to override in the same manner

}
```

Either use auto-detect feature of Spring or you can define a bean in your spring xml configuration file as shown below and use this bean in you respective job.

```
<bean id="myJdbcWriter" class="com.x.y.z.MyCustomJdbcWriter"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I've already tried that, and it gives me this exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An SQL statement is required. I tried adding an sql property but, since this is a writer, I don't see which kind of SQL request I might use.

Comment: `An SQL statement is required`. Its talking about [JdbcCursorItemReader.setSql()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html#setSql%28java.lang.String%29). I think you have missed to provide all the required properties of reader/writer. Please have a look again.

Comment: Please share your configuration file.

Comment: Apparently, it was a "entityManagerFactory" problem. I just changed the datasource of entityManagerFactory bean. Now, it works fine. Thank you very much for your help Braj!